# Getting Change Management records with Service Now API

Tags: c#, .net, webservice-client, servicenow, change-management

I am having the change management number `CH****12`. I want to get the records for this change management number in [ServiceNow](https://www.servicenow.com/support.html) API.

For example, I had `incident` number and **got** the records with incident number `INC*****12` through accessing `https://instance.service-now.com/incident.do?SOAP` service url and appropriate credentials(username and  password) with [getRecords](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Microsoft_.NET_Web_Services_Client_Examples#getRecords).

Similarly, I want to ***get records*** for the given ***change management number***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the change management service `url` and used it.

```
https://instance.service-now.com/change_request.do?SOAP
```

It contains `getRecords` function and it gives the corresponding record after providing the change management number as input.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the ServiceNow [REST Table API](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Table_API) for this type of request. Using the REST table API the URL for a specific Change Request would be:
https://{instance_name}.service-now.com/api/now/table/change_request/{sys_id}

Where sys_id is the id of the Change Request you want to retrieve.

For Example: https://{instance_name}.service-now.com/api/now/table/change_request/a9e9c33dc61122760072455df62663d2.

If you are using ServiceNow Fuji Release you can use the [REST API Explorer](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=REST_API_Explorer) to help you build and test these requests.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
https://instance.service-now.com/change_request.do?JSONv2=&sysparm_action=getRecords&sysparm_query=number=CHG000001
```

The above query should work. Change instance.service-now.com to your service now DNS name.